# Using the Consolibyte PHP SDK for QuickBooks, what is the correct syntax for a Query?

Tags: php, desktop, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I've looked all over and cannot find this. What is the qbXML to query a customer (or invoice, or payment, or whatever) using the ListID? I'm currently sending something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <CustomerQueryRq requestID="' + $requestID + '">
            <ListID>' + $qbDesktopID + '</ListID>
        </CustomerQueryRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Where that qbDesktopID looks like 80000000-1234567890, and I'm receiving a somewhat generic error that says my XML isn't properly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few really important things to note here:

1. For troubleshooting, it's important that you look at *the actual qbXML you're sending* vs. *your code*. What does *the actual qbXML you're sending to QuickBooks* look like? You can find this in the `quickbooks_log` SQL table, and also in the Web Connector log (if you set it to `VERBOSE` logging).
2. Invoices and payments don't have `ListID` values, so be aware those queries will be different (they have `TxnID` values instead).
3. Anytime you get an error message, it's important that you post *the actual error message*. QuickBooks produces literally thousands of different error messages, so without knowing specifically what error you're getting it's really hard to assist you.
4. Anytime you get an error related to qbXML syntax, your first stop should be the `XML Validator` tool *included with the QuickBooks SDK*. It will literally tell you exactly which line and character is incorrect.

With all that said... I suspect that you're not actually sending what you think you're sending.

The PHP concatenation operator for strings *is not `+`*. It's `.`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Assuming what you posted above is a snippet of PHP, it evaluates to an empty string or possibly an integer (if `$requestID` is an integer) and not a valid XML string.

Are you sure you didn't mean:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <CustomerQueryRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
            <ListID>' . $qbDesktopID . '</ListID>
        </CustomerQueryRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>';
```

(note the `.` instead of `+` for concatenation)